# relative path in project Java EE with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, relative-path

I want upload file in /WEB-INF/files using a relative path in Bean. I using Maven project Java EE in Eclipse. this is part of code in Bean (package Service.Bean):

```
// Create file with unique name in upload folder and write to it.
file = File.createTempFile(prefix + "_", "." + suffix,new File("/WEB-INF/files"));
output = new FileOutputStream(file);
IOUtils.copy(uploadedFile.getInputstream(), output);
fileName = file.getName();
```

this is Exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at service.FileUploadController.handleFileUpload(FileUploadController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:277)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

`/WEB-INF/files` is an absolute path, so the `File.createTempFile` method searches for a `WEB-INF` folder under the root of your file system and can't find it. It's better to use:

> new
>   File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("../files").toURI())

since the default classpath in a WAR is `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: but i have message erreur in this ligne : 
file = File.createTempFile(prefix + "_", "." + suffix,new File(ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/files").toURI())); 

message erreur : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResource(String) from the type

Comment: I didn't notice it was inside a bean, no servlet context! I've edited my answer.

Comment: but we using this method ,I get relative path of Classes Directory ??
me I want get the relative path of directory /src/ressource (for exemple) ??

Comment: Just look at where your directory is deployed and then use relative paths starting from the classes folder up to that location.

Comment: I used this solution in normal JEE Project,but my project is created with Maven project

Comment: I don't understand the difference between a JEE project and a Maven one